# get the start and the end date of every week leading up to the current date

Tags: python, datetime, calendar

I've done some research on this and haven't found anything that close to what I want. starting out i'm pretty new to python, so most of my python is not very 'pythonic' .. that aside what I want is to get the start date and end date of every week leading up to the current date. mostly I wanted to get **recommendations** of what way to go about it as there are multiple different ways to do it. should I look into building it off of the `week number`? or just by using `datetime`?

I was hoping to build it in this format

```
[{
    'start': 2013-12-30,
    'end': 2014-01-05
},{
    'start': 2014-01-06,
    'end': 2014-01-12
}... etc]
```

---

My initial attempt:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

def get_week_days(self, year, week, **kwd):
    d = date(year,1,1)
    if(d.weekday()>3):
        d = d+timedelta(7-d.weekday())
    else:
        d = d - timedelta(d.weekday())
    dlt = timedelta(days = (week-2)*7)
    last_wk = {}
    last_wk['start'] = d + dlt
    last_wk['end'] = d + dlt + timedelta(days=6)
    return last_wk
```

this returns the start and end date of a given week by week number. I could do a loop and call this function the number of weeks there has been in the year, but I'm not sure if that is efficient, or if this method can / should be cleaned up?

any recommendations on how i should go about it would be helpful :) thanks

Comment: Do all of your weeks start on Jan. 1? Also I'm curious, I know in Europe it's common to format dates as dd/mm/yyyy, but who uses yyyy-dd-mm? The ISO standard is yyyy-mm-dd and it's confusing to see it the other way around.

Comment: the week starting on jan first was just for an example. the format is another thing that was an example. its in yyyy-mm-dd, i just wrote it backwards. im using yyyy-mm-dd as that is how its laid out in the database i have to work with :) i went ahead and edited it for you so its in the correct format and on the correct dates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, calling your method in a loop will certainly work. The disadvantage to that is that you have to recreate everything with every call of the method. Since weeks are sequential, it might be better to find the first week and then add 1 day to find the beginning of the next week. This way you're building off of your previous work and don't need to recreate all of your objects.

One way to do this would be with a `getNextWeek` method.

```
def getNextWeek(week):
  nextWeek = {};
  nextWeek['start'] = week['end'] + timedelta(days=1)
  nextWeek['end'] = nextWeek['start'] + timedelta(days=6)
  return nextWeek
```

Comment: Ok that seems workable :) so on the method I wrote there seems to be a problem with it because if my week number is 0, 1 or 2 it returns weeks before december 30th of 2013.. would you know where my error is?

Comment: @JohnRuddell I haven't done much with `date` or `timedelta`, but I'll bet the documentation has an explanation for that behavior.